# error on sending skype BOT messges

Tags: node.js, api, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have obtained the access token via https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token and with that token tried to send a message using this url https://apis.skype.com/v3/conversations/conversationId/activities/. But  i am getting this error "401: The provided 'OAuth' ticket failed authentication.".

What could be the issue here